# Amazon S3 does not release the file after the upload

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I have a wcf service here to upload the files to Amazon s3 server. After the successful upload, I need to delete the file from my local path. But when I try to delete the file, got an error says  The process cannot access the file.Because its being used by another process".Sharing below my code snippets.

```
var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["S3Bucket"]
                       .ToString(),
    Key = keyName,
    FilePath = path,
    ContentType = "application/pdf"
};

client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);
PutObjectResponse response = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);
putRequest = null;
client.Dispose();  
File.Delete(path);
```

If anyone know about the issue, please update..

Comment: What if you put all the S3 code (before the deletion) into a `using` block?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a timing issue here, so you might want to try to close the stream explicitly.

Do note, I am not sure, if I am mistaken I'll remove this, but it was to long for a comment.

```
using (var fileStream = new File.OpenRead(path))
{
    var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["S3Bucket"]
                    .ToString(),
        Key = keyName,
        InputStream = fileStream ,
        ContentType = "application/pdf",
        AutoCloseStream = false,
    };

    using (var c = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion))
    {
         PutObjectResponse response = await c.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);
    }
} //filestream should be closed here, if not: call fileStream.Close() 

File.Delete(path);
```

More info on the properties: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_PutObjectRequest.htm

Comment: I tried with your code.But failed to upload the file, got error says "Access Denied"

Comment: Thats odd.... is the file already open? In that case, being unable to delete it makes sense as well